# Exporting raster over loop in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, loop

I would like to export raster in a foreach loop with :

```
var landCover = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/2016_01_01').select('LC_Prop1');
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

var Country_array = ['Kenya', 'Senegal', 
                     'Mozambique', 'Comoros', 
                     'France', 'Cambodia',
                     'Colombia','Gabon'];
Country_array.forEach(function(c) {
  print(c);
  var sel = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', c));
    var modis2017 = ee.Image(landCover)
                .clip(sel);

    Export.image.toDrive({
      image : modis2017,
      description: 'image'.concat('_', c),
      //maxPixels: 3784216672400,
      scale: 1000,
      crs : 'EPSG:4326',
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
      });

   // display
  Map.addLayer(sel, {}, 'shp'.concat('_', c));
  Map.addLayer(modis2017, {}, 'r'.concat('_', c));

});
```

but it produces empty (black) images. I don't understand why.

Comment: Does the export for a single country work, without the loop?

Comment: Yes it work outside de loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why but it works whit `region: sel.geometry().bounds()` ...  :

```
var landCover = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/2016_01_01').select('LC_Prop1');
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

var Country_array = ['Kenya', 'Senegal', 
                     'Mozambique', 'Comoros', 
                     'France', 'Cambodia',
                     'Colombia','Gabon'];
Country_array.forEach(function(c) {
  print(c);
  var sel = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', c));
    var modis2017 = ee.Image(landCover)
                .clip(sel);

    Export.image.toDrive({
      image : modis2017,
      description: 'image'.concat('_', c),
      //maxPixels: 3784216672400,
      scale: 1000,
      crs : 'EPSG:4326',
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
      region: sel.geometry().bounds()
      });

   // display
  Map.addLayer(sel, {}, 'shp'.concat('_', c));
  Map.addLayer(modis2017, {}, 'r'.concat('_', c));

});
```