# Casting computed list by using 'forEach' reducer method

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I adapted the code in [Export raster over a loop in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307577) for adding raster layers by using a dates list instead a country names list. Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aadbcfae21a5c9f77a7d2665ab48f3d3) looks as follows.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[81.0312993277979, 29.97063836127144],
          [81.0312993277979, 28.91826467453208],
          [83.2505376090479, 28.91826467453208],
          [83.2505376090479, 29.97063836127144]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(aoi);
Map.addLayer(aoi);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-30'); // // %Y-%m-%d

var scale = s2.first().select('B1').projection().nominalScale();

print(scale);

//print(s2);

// Function to mosaic by date, orbit, etc
function mosaicBy(imcol){
  // imcol: An image collection
  // returns: An image collection

  // return the collection as a list of images (not an image collection)
  var imlist = imcol.toList(imcol.size());

  // Get all the dates as list
  var all_dates = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd");
  });

  // get all orbits as list
  var all_orbits = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).get('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER');
  });

  // get all spacecraft names as list
  var all_spNames = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).get('SPACECRAFT_NAME');
  });

  // this puts dates, orbits and names into a nested list
  var concat_all = all_dates.zip(all_orbits).zip(all_spNames);

  // here we unnest the list with flatten, and then concatenate the list elements with " "
  concat_all = concat_all.map(function(el){
    return ee.List(el).flatten().join(" ");
    });

  // here, just get distinct combintations of date, orbit and name
  var concat_unique = concat_all.distinct();

  // mosaic
  var mosaic_imlist = concat_unique.map(function(d){

    // split into components
    var d1 = ee.String(d).split(" ");

    var date1 = ee.Date(d1.get(0));
    var orbit = ee.Number.parse(d1.get(1)).toInt();
    var spName = ee.String(d1.get(2));

    var im = imcol
      .filterDate(date1, date1.advance(1, "day")) // filter with start date, and then end date, ie date + 1 day
      .filterMetadata('SPACECRAFT_NAME', 'equals', spName)
      .filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER','equals', orbit)
      .mosaic();

    return im.set(
        "system:time_start", date1.millis(),
        "system:date", date1.format("YYYY-MM-dd"),
        "system:id", d1);
  });

  return ee.ImageCollection(mosaic_imlist);
}


var s2day = mosaicBy(s2);

print(s2day);

// Make list of image to display each one
var listOfImages = s2day.toList(s2day.size());

var allDates = s2day.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });
  
print("allDatesSimple", allDatesSimple);

var dates = listOfImages.map(function(ele) {
  
  return ee.Image(ele).get('system:date');
  
});

print("dates", dates);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

var dates_array = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07',
                   '2019-01-09', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-16',
                   '2019-01-17', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-24',
                   '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-29'];

print("dates_array", dates_array);

dates_array.forEach(function(c) {
  
  var idx = dates_array.indexOf(c);
  
  var test = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(idx));

  test = test
    .clip(aoi);

  Map.addLayer(test, {}, 'image'.concat('_', c));
  
});
```

Dates list was defined as follows and the code works without any issue.

```
var dates_array = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07',
                   '2019-01-09', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-16',
                   '2019-01-17', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-24',
                   '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-29'];
```

On the other hand, if I have a huge list of dates, it is preferable to use a different way for obtaining that list. It can be afforded by using following code lines because dates were added as property ('system:date').

```
var listOfImages = s2day.toList(s2day.size());

var dates = listOfImages.map(function(ele) {
  
  return ee.Image(ele).get('system:date');
  
});

print("dates", dates);
```

However, this list produces a 'not a function' error. So, I explored 'forEach' documentation and found out it is a **ee.Reducer** method. I used different ways for incorporating it by using 'reduce' list method unsuccesfully.

When I explicity cast **dates_array** as list (or array), as follows, code doesn't work.

```
var dates_array = ee.List(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07',
                       '2019-01-09', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-16',
                       '2019-01-17', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-24',
                       '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-29']);
```

On the other hand, in the functional code, both lists (**dates_array** and **dates**) are identical when they were printed.

Is there a way for transforming a **dates** computed object in a list that is capable to be used with the 'forEach' method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forEach function that your original code is using, is a client-side function on Javascript arrays/lists.  You cannot use it on server-side objects.

In your original code, you have a client-side javascript list.  In the second code, you've turned it into a server side list.  The only way to use the server-side list in a loop like you're using, is to retrieve it from the server to the client with `getInfo` or `evaluate`.

(The forEach function in Reducer is irrelevant here, it's only usable for generating multiple reducers).

Comment: Thank you. It worked just as you pointed out.